# Using hibernate and ms sql server driver

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc, orm

Microsoft doesn't supply jdbc jar to central maven repository. It needs register driver manually.
But I make something wrong. I saw same exception trace:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" class not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at logic.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:22)
    at logic.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at logic.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" class not found
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
    at logic.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class ["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:104)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
    ... 17 more
```

I use STS(eclipse product)
in maven dependencies :
[image]

What do I make wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JRE version 6.0 or 7.0 then use sqljdbc4.jar file. If the JRE version is 5.0 then use sqljdbc.jar file.

These jar files can be downloaded from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx)

Also you can get more clarity about System Requirements for the JDBC Driver from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx)

Comment: Can you please let me know that which JRE version is installed on the machine?

Comment: I use 6 version of JRE

Comment: Well then everything seems to be fine. Please make sure that in the final deployment file i.e. war file sqljdbc4-3.0.jar file is in WEB-INF/lib folder. The problem clear says that its unable to find the class file.

Comment: It is not web application

Comment: Well try it another way. Go to your JDK_Home directory, under this directory go to jre->lib and paste sqljdbc4-3.0.jar file in lib directory. In this way your problem will be fixed. Also the second and professional solution is that go to Advanced system settings, open Advanced tab, click on Environment Variables button edit Path system variable by adding your libraries path i.e. ;path to your libraries. But make sure that all libraries should be in one directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following properties are correctly configured or not

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=<dbname>;</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
```